# Excel VBA to automatically create row numbers

Tags: excel, vba, row, cell

I went online searching for an excel VBA code to automatically enter the row numbers in a column and I found the code below. It works beautiful except that it detects every cell clicked in the sheet. I would like to change it so that it only detects the cells in the table or, if that’s not possible, that it detects only the cells in the A column. How can I change it? My table has 8 columns A:H

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit 
 
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) 
    Dim RowOffset As Long 
    Dim IndexCol As String 
     'Set values
    RowOffset = 0 
     'Change the C to the column where you want the numbers to show
    IndexCol = "C" 
     
    Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireRow, Columns(IndexCol)).Value = ActiveCell.Row + RowOffset 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)` gives you a range variable named `Target` which represents the range that has been selected. Use that variable in your code to check if the column is one that you want to act on.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim RowOffset As Long
    Dim IndexCol As String
    
    'Check if clicked cell is in specified columns
    If Target.Column >= 1 And Target.Column <= 8 Then
         
         'Set values
        RowOffset = 0
         'Change the C to the column where you want the numbers to show
        IndexCol = "C"
        
        Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireRow, Columns(IndexCol)).Value = ActiveCell.Row + RowOffset
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin, that’s all I needed, it works just as I was hoping 

Comment: @learningcodes In that case, why not end this question by accepting Kevin's answer?